# How to access Hive using a Java API

Tags: hive

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hive/HiveJDBCInterface - Is there a higher level ORM interface than the Hive JDBC driver which we can use to run the queries and parse the results

Comment: Hey, did you get to an interface up the ladder of abstraction to work with hive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. The "R" in ORM stands for a "relational database". Hive is a NOSQL databse, not a relational database. It's a huge advantage of Hive comparing to many other NOSQL databases that you can access it using (almost) normal SQL and using (almost) full featured standard JDBC interface. But if you are thinking about using ORM and Hive together, you might be approaching your problem from an incorrect angle.

**EDIT 6/4/13:** Here's a quote from Wikipedia: In the relational model, each table schema must identify a primary column used for identifying a row called the primary key. Tables can relate by using a foreign key that points to the primary key.

Hive does not support neither foreign nor primary keys, so it is not a relational database.

I would like to thank the downvoter for giving me an opportunity to doublecheck the reasoning that led to making my original statement.

Comment: Trying to program to the JDBC interface is quite primitive, would prefer to program to a slightly higher abstraction since I am used to programming to the JPA layer a lot. Hence my question.

Comment: What kind of data you are trying to store in Hive? Hive is at it's best when handling very big, very flat tables. If your data model complex enough to benefit form an ORM, you might be looking at a wrong tool.

Comment: It's very hard for me to see how Hive is a NoSQL database, since the primary way of interacting with it is through SQL. In fact, I'd say it's the whole _point_ of Hive to _be_ a SQL database. Maybe not a relational one (as Olaf points out)

Comment: Hive is actually a warehouse that runs on top of your Hadoop cluster. And even if I try to think of it from a database point of view, then Hive is not a full database. The design constraints and limitations of Hadoop and HDFS impose limits on what Hive can do. The biggest limitation is that Hive does not provide record-level update, insert, nor delete. Hive does not provide transactions either. Apart from the warehousing capability Hive provides an SQL dialect, called Hive Query Language for querying data stored in a Hadoop cluster. SO, people sometimes get confused and think of it as a DB.

Comment: @Olaf : IMHO, Hive is not a DB, neither SQL nor NoSQL. As per my understanding the Hive concept of a database is essentially just a catalog or namespace of tables to avoiding table name collisions and to organize production tables into logical groups. Nothing more than that. So, Hive doesn't actually qualify to be a database. But, this is just what I think. Views may vary. BTW you are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Hive is an eco-system component on top of Hadoop. It is not either a RDBMS or NOSQL Databases, it is just way of writing MapReduce programming on top of HDFS(filesystem).

Hive is created inorder to make developer friendly one who have sql knowledge can easily run MapReduce with just writing an sql kind of statements. The MapReduce can be expressed as an sql where Hive engine convert them to MapReduce using Driver.

Hive make division of storage and its structure using metastore.
Metastore is simple RDBMS, like any other RDBMS we can connect to it and make an sql statement on top of this.Once we made an HQL statement on Metastore, the metastore have a capability to tell underline Hive engine to execute HQL statement and gives back the result as a resultset.